# Batch update not sending any array data to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting no error while batch update of array data. The submit and show me no error. Could you please help me to figure this problem out.

```
$invoice_id = $this->input->post('id');
$desc       =   $this->input->post('desc[]');
$size       =   $this->input->post('size[]');
$stock      =   $this->input->post('stock[]');
$color      =   $this->input->post('color[]');
$qty        =   $this->input->post('qty[]');
$price      =   $this->input->post('price[]');
$linetotal  =   $this->input->post('linetotal[]');  

$invoice_id = $this->input->post('id');
$input_data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($desc); $i++ )
{
    $input_data[] = array(
        'desc'          =>  $desc[$i],
        'size'          =>  $size[$i],
        'stock'         =>  $stock[$i], 
        'color'         =>  $color[$i],
        'qty'           =>  $qty[$i],   
        'price'         =>  $price[$i],
        'linetotal'     =>  $linetotal[$i],
    );
}

$this->db->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
$this->db->update_batch('invoice_data',$input_data, 'invoice_id');
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Data added successfully.');
redirect('invoices');
```

I am using id field in my view too. But can't get the data updated.

Comment: Dunno if it makes a difference, but try e.g. `$this->input->post('desc')` instead? I.e.g without the `[]`?

Comment: Let me try @Jonnix

Comment: Like @Jonnix says, you need to fetch the values without the `[]` in the end. The name is just `desc`. The `[]` is just to say that it should be an array instead of a single value.

Comment: No luck with this trick @Jonnix

Comment: @TheCustomPack What do you get when you `var_dump($this->input->post(null, false))`?

Comment: @Jonnix I am Getting this one. please check: https://imgur.com/a/lu1irkn

Comment: Wait wait, you've changed `desc` to `invoice_id`. But that doesn't exist inside your `$input_data` array.

Comment: Ya i have changed, can i add invoice_id into the input_data

Comment: @Jonnix still cant work, after including $input_data

Comment: @Jonnix Still Cant fix it. Please help me in this